# probability question from econ class with cdf of standard normal dist

Tags: probability

We have

$$
Pr\big(\frac{v}{\sigma_v} > \frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v}\big)
$$

and then we do

$$
1-Pr\big(\frac{v}{\sigma_v} \leq \frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v}\big)
$$

then part I don't understand is that the next thing we have is

$$
1-\Phi\big(\frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v}\big)
$$

where $\Phi$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution

How does 2 turn into 3?

Comment: -1 for not even bothering to proof-read what you have typed. Equation numbers are missing, and I am sure that your Econ class had $\sigma_v$ where you have written $\sigma v$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'm not very good at Latex, in fact everything I know about latex I just learned to type this question up so I'm sorry I didn't label the equations (and still haven't).  I presume anyone who knows how to answer this question is also capable of counting to 3.  As to your second charge, yes the v was subscripted and I did fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that $v$ is a random variable and it is distributed as $v\sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_v^2)$. Therefore $\frac{v}{\sigma_v}$ is distributed as $\frac{v}{\sigma_v}\sim  \mathcal N(0,1)$, which means that this random variable is standard normally distributed.

Now you can write $1-Pr\left(\frac{v}{\sigma_v}\leq \frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v}\right)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v} \right)$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of a normally distributed random variable, where $z=\frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v}$

$\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v} \right)$ returns the value of the probability that the normally distributed random variable $\frac{v}{\sigma_v}$ is smaller (or equal) than the value $\frac{\mu_0-\mu_1+\pi}{\sigma_v}$. It is fair to say that the different expressions are different notations only.